# Getting same IP address for cloned Virtual Images

Tags: dhcp, virtual-machines, virtualbox, dhcp-server

I was trying to install 3 VM and instead of creating them individually (by using the New VM) I actually cloned them. Now after I start the VM (they are running in the bridge mode) all the VM's are getting the same IP address. I'm using auto DHCP for them to fetch IP addresses.

Is it because I cloned them they are having the same MAC address?

Also I was interested to know if DHCP sees the MAC address to give IP's?

I am not sure why this is happening, I struggled and finally when I installed each one separately I was getting different IP addresses.

I am not so familiar with Virtualization technology and I preferred Virtual Box cause of its simplicity (found it more easier than XEN :P)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it because I cloned them they are having the same MAC address??

Depends on the clone process and hypervisor in question.  It certainly sounds like you duplicated MAC addresses though.  I am not very familiar with virtual box, but I am almost certain there was an option somewhere to re-generate the MAC address for an interface.  I know other VM software like Vmware has this option.

> Also I was interested to know if DHCP sees the MAC address to give IP's??

DHCP is keyed on the MAC address.  A DHCP server will only give out one IP per MAC.  If you have many devices on your network with same MAC address, then you have far more serious problems then just DHCP though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I also happened to check the following [link] (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/Networking)
As you mentioned that same MAC addresses can give me more serious problems, I was curious to know what those can be.

Comment: Take a look to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/655746/500826).